# Python Pandas Calculate Number of values in columns for each row and put it in columns

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say that I have a dataframe like:

```
    x     y
1   45    T
2   70    T
3   88    F
4   45    F
5   88    F
..
```

And I want to calculate the value_counts for both columns together, and put them in separated columns:

```
    x     y    z
1   45    1    1
2   70    1    0
3   88    0    2
..
```

Where x is the plain number I have (integers), and y is the number of T values it got in the original dataframe, and z is the number of F values it got.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) + [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) + [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = pd.crosstab(df['x'], df['y']).reset_index().rename_axis(None, 1)
print (df)
    x  F  T
0  45  1  1
1  70  0  1
2  88  2  0
```

Alternative with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) + [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['x','y'])
       .size()
       .unstack(fill_value=0)
       .reset_index().rename_axis(None, 1)
print (df)
    x  F  T
0  45  1  1
1  70  0  1
2  88  2  0
```

But if need rename columns (but need only few unique values in `y`) need `dict`:

```
d = {'T':'y','F':'z'}
df = df.groupby(['x','y'])
       .size()
       .unstack(fill_value=0)
       .rename(columns=d)
       .rename_axis(None, 1)
       .reset_index()
print (df)
    x  z  y
0  45  1  1
1  70  0  1
2  88  2  0
```

Comment: Not even 1 minute, Great :)

Comment: @RahulKP - Thanks.